# Using the pigeonhole principle to prove there is at least a sum of numbers bigger than 29.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

There is a circumference with 14 points $\{p_{1}, p_{2}, ... p_{14}\}$. These points are assigned numbers 1 to 14 randomly. It must be proven that if points are taken three-by-three, these triplets being formed by consecutive points, there will be at least one triplet which has a sum bigger than 29.

This is how I operated:

There are 14 sums $\{s_{1}, s_{2}, ... s_{14}\}$ where $$s_{1} = p_{1} + p_{2} + p_{3}$$$$s_{2} = p_{2} + p_{3} + p_{4}$$$$...$$$$s_{14} = p_{14} + p_{1} + p_{2}$$ So each number appears 3 times, this is $$s_{1}+s_{2}+...+s_{14} = 3*(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14) = 315$$ And, $$14*29 = 406$$ This is where I get stuck and don't know how to prove the statement using the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Use $1,14,2,13,3,12,4,11,5,10,6,9,7,8$. The biggest sum is $29$, not bigger than $29$. One can do better.

Comment: Your argument has the right structure, but you were asked to prove something that is not true.

Comment: OK. That's what I suspected. If it were 22 and not 29, would the prove be 14*22 = 308. And 308 < 315 so some triplets bigger than 22?

Comment: Yes, bigger than $22$ follows from your argument. And I am sure one can use a larger number than $22$ by a more delicate argument. But bigger than $29$ is false.

Comment: OK. Thanks you.

Comment: Note that $315/14=22.5$. This means that we could only achieve the minimum value of $23$ by alternating between $22$ and $23$ (since adjacent sums cannot be equal). However this cannot be achieved either, since the alternating sum argument requires values 6 points apart to be equal. Thus the smallest maximum sum possible is 24, achieved with $\{14,3,7,13,2,9,12,1,11,8,5,10,6,4\}$ for example.